# Flex 4 Dynamically Loading CSS Makes App Invisible

Tags: css, apache-flex

I dynamically load my CSS stylesheet on launching my application using FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.styleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("styles.css"). The style loads fine but I have a problem where my application appears invisible for a second or so until the css has been fully loaded I assume and applied to my app.

When I was using Flex 3 and had StyleManager.loadStyleDeclaration() I didn't have this problem. Does anyone know how to solve this?